# What to modify after forking a .NET/WiX project, so that both original and fork can be installed alongside?

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer, packaging, visual-c#-express-2010

I forked a .NET/WiX product ("[SparkleShare](https://github.com/hbons/SparkleShare)") into a completely different product ("[CmisSync](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/CmisSync)").

Users should be able to install both products if they wish.

Unfortunately, when one is installed then the other can not be installed:

> Another version of this product is already installed Installation of this version cannot continue.To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove program on the Control Panel

What must I change?
It is a .NET 4.5 multi-projects solution in Visual C# 2010 Express, WiX-generated installer.

I want to share code often between projects, so the source code must stay as identical as possible. For this reason, many "SparkleShare" strings remain, that is on purpose, I want to modify **only where necessary**.

Here is what I think is the interesting part of [SparkleShare.wxs](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/CmisSync/blob/master/SparkleShare/Windows/SparkleShare.wxs):

```
<Product Name='CmisSync' Id='184950D5-67F6-4D06-9717-7E2F1607A7B0' UpgradeCode='D3DF1D99-87F5-47A7-A349-863DD6E4B73A'
Language='1033' Codepage='1252' Version='0.8.1' Manufacturer='SparkleShare'>

<Package Id='*' Keywords='Installer' Description="CmisSync Setup" Manufacturer='CmisSync'
  InstallerVersion='100' Languages='1033' Compressed='yes' SummaryCodepage='1252' />

<Media Id='1' Cabinet='SparkleShare.cab' EmbedCab='yes' DiskPrompt='SparkleShare CAB' />
<Property Id='DiskPrompt' Value="SparkleShare Bundle CAB Installation" />

<Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
  <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder' Name='PFiles'>
      <Directory Id='INSTALLDIR' Name='CmisSync'>
        <Component Id='SparkleShare.exe' Guid='0DA582D5-4ABE-4251-9F62-E7DEA76F10E1'>
          <File Id='SparkleShare.exe' Name='SparkleShare.exe' Source='!(wix.root)\bin\SparkleShare.exe' KeyPath='yes' DiskId='1' />
```

I have only changed the places where "CmisSync" is written. What else MUST I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change the guid's in the `UpgradeCode` and the `Id` attributes in the `Product` element. The `UpgradeCode` is what determines that it is the same application. Once you have changed the `UpgradeCode`, do not change it again otherwise it will not be able to detect and remove existing versions. The `Id` needs to be changed per version of your application along with the `Version` attribute